# I want to determine the lenght of $x$ by making equations for each triangle ACD and ADB.

Tags: geometry, circles

[image]

I want to determine the lenght of $x$ by making equations for each triangle ACD and ADB.

Let's recall $\angle DAB = \alpha $, $\angle DBA = \beta $ in triangle ADB

$$\alpha + \beta + 90 = 180$$

$$\alpha + \beta =180 \tag{1}$$

In isosceles triangle ACD, $\angle CAD = \angle CDA = \alpha$ and let $\angle ACD = \theta $

$$2\alpha + \theta = 180 \tag{2}$$

From two equations, we can conclude that $\alpha = 2\beta$. However, this does not actually help me at all. What am I missing?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Enzo
Call $t=AC=CD=DB$. From Pythagorean Theorem you have
$$
10^2=t^2+x^2
$$
From the law of cosines in triangle $ACD$ you get
$$
2t^2-2t^2\cos\theta=x^2
$$
But $\cos\theta=\cos(180-2\alpha)=-\cos(2\alpha)=1-2\cos^2\alpha=1-2(t/10)^2$. If you plug this value in the second displayed equation above you get a system for $x$ and $t$ that reduces to a quadratic equation for either $t^2$ or $x^2$

Answer (score 1):

You can conclude by observing that $\angle ADB$ is inscribed in a semicircle and is therefore right.  This means that $\alpha + \beta = 90$, so $\alpha = 30$ and $\beta = 60$.  It follows that $x = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(10) = 5 \sqrt{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\alpha + \beta + 90 = 180, \, \beta= 2 \alpha,\,3 \alpha= 90, \, \alpha=30,\, \beta=60$$

Use Rule of Sines on right triangle $ \Delta ADB$ inside semi-circle $ACDB$

$$  \dfrac{x}{\sin 60}= \dfrac{10}{\sin 90} \rightarrow x= 10 \sqrt{3}/2 $$

Comment: There's a typo, I meant to write $\theta = 2\beta$. How can we conclude that it is also right for $ 2\alpha = \beta$?

Comment: You should correct your question to be without typo.